# Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38 Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a situation where, every 10 seconds, an error log is recorded with the following message:

```
2018-07-25 09:07:09.59 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2018-07-25 09:07:09.59 Logon       Login failed for user 'svc_sql'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

In my instance I don't have a 'ReportServer' database. I know that in the past the server was migrated to a new machine and I reckon the 'ReportServer' database was created with a new name in the new server. I really don't know how the migration was done.

I've activated the SQL_Profiler with all audit options and I could see that this user also executes a procedure sometimes.

I've checked the default database for this user and it is Master.

Any ideas how can I fix this issue? My error log is flooding with this message.

Comment: Do you know what is calling the request to access the server? Is there a job that is running that uses the name/database?

Comment: I've checked all jobs, I couldn't find anything and no users are complaining about jobs failing. The SQL Profile outcome showed me only one procedure that runs with this user and doesn't  try to connect to a 'ReportServer' database. I think that  some internal reference still pointing this user to 'ReportServer'. I'm  not sure... I don't know if I try to run DBCC CHECKDB master will solve this.

Answer (score 2):

> I've checked the default database for this user and it's Master.

The error doesn't tell you about `default` database but about **explicitly specified** database, that is different, it's the database that is mentioned in connection string under `Initial Catalog` or `Database`.

Do you see what application tries to open this database? The problem is in that application, it uses old connection string. If it's `SSMS`, it's simple, it's in the `Options` of connection dialog, but if it's another application, the connection string can be written in the `ini` file or hardcoded.

> I don't know if I try to run DBCC CHECKDB master will solve this.

Of course it cannot solve this. This has nothing to do with database integrity. It's your client that uses wrong connection string.

> Any ideas how can I fix this issue? My error log is flooding with this
>   message.

If you just want to save your errorlog from these messages just turn off `failed logins audit`:

[image]

Or you should find this application by its name or host or client address.

Or you can temporarily disable this login and see who will call you saying he cannot login anymore, or, if it's your local machine, some of your applications will fail, this way you'll find it.

Comment: Disabling failed login auditing is a very bad idea. Malicious login attempts can now be made and you will be none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem because I frequently restore my prod database to my test database, which copies all logins and user data.  Herein lies the problem because I generally change the passwords for my test database so they are not the same as production.  This causes the sev 14 error when my service tries to log in.

This can be remedied with:

```
ALTER USER [MyUser] WITH LOGIN = [MyUser]
```

I'm not sure exactly what is happening here, but I believe this is because the SIDs are not the same following a restore.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error and doing the following resolved the error for me:
From within the SQL Server Management Studio

1. Security
2. Logins
3. Right Click the user ID that was failing login
4. Server Roles
5. Make sure all the checkboxes are checked. Right clicked Security and refresh.

Comment: Granting all server roles to a login is not a way to fix permissions. One must understand why the issue is arising, and take appropriate measures. Granting sysadmin privileges should only be for true sysadmins.

Comment: In this instance, I should have noted that this was for a local development environment. All those roles were appropriate for my purposes.